# Weird scrolling behavior and visibility of Persistent or Standard BottomSheet in a page having RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

As one can see in image, **RecyclerView** items are visible through **Standard/Persistent BottomSheet** and collapsing/expanding of BottomSheet is also not happening in **Standard/Persistent BottomSheet**. **RecyclerView** items are scrollable but when I do any kind of activity in **Standard/Persistent BottomSheet**, it directly scrolling the **RecyclerView** item behind this **Standard/Persistent BottomSheet**.

**Note:** Background color used in BottomSheet is solid. It's not transparent.

I'm wondering how to solve this issue?

Here's the code snippet ->

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/layout_container_main"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context="app.standardbottomsheet.ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_container_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:context="app.standardbottomsheet.ui.MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/included_layout_standard_bottom_sheet"
            layout="@layout/layout_standard_bottom_sheet" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

layout_standard_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="?actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/summary" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: I have implemented MainActivity having a recyclerview with multiple items in it and Standard bottom sheet.]

Comment: recyclerView is being scrolled because it looks like the bottom sheet is behind the recyclerView and touch events are being intercepted by recyclerView only, not reaching the bottom sheet I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the image your bottom sheet is behind the recycler view. To change that you have to change the order of recyclerview and coordinatelayour in your `activity_main.xml`

You can try by changing the order like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.standardbottomsheet.ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_container_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:context="app.standardbottomsheet.ui.MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/included_layout_standard_bottom_sheet"
            layout="@layout/layout_standard_bottom_sheet" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Since both recycler view and CoordinatorLayout are `match_parent`, There order decide which is above to another.

Comment: It's working now perfectly brother...I spent 2 days on this small issue...Grrr. Thanks a lot for clearing doubts and solving this issue...  :-)